# How do I display file names that contain two characters and one of them is c?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filenames, command

I tried doing `ls [a-z][a-z]`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Names of _regular files_ or any filename (symbolic links, names of directories, or otherwise)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With bash, set the glob settings so that missing matches don't trigger an error:

```
shopt -u failglob  # avoid failure report (and discarding the whole line).
shopt -s nullglob  # remove (erase) non-matching globs.
ls ?c c?
```

Question-mark is a glob character representing a single character. Since you want two-character filenames, one of them has to be a `c`, and so it's either the first character or the last character.

With `shopt -s dotglob` this would also surface a file named `.c`.

If there are no matching files, setting these shell options causes all of the arguments to be removed, resulting in a bare `ls` -- listing anything/everything by default.

Use this, instead:

```
shopt -s nullglob  ## drop any missing globs
set -- ?c c?       ## populate the $@ array with (any) matches
if [ $# -gt 0 ]    ## if there are some, list them
  ls -d "$@"
fi
```

Comment: You may also want to use `nullglob`?

Comment: erm, not quite -- failglob removes the error but also removes everything (thus listing everything) if there are no matches

Comment: a file named cc is print 2 times

Comment: We'll need clarification on whether a file named `cc` consists of "one" c :)

Answer (score 10):

I think the better way is to use `find` :

```
find . -type f -name '*c*' -name '??'
```

That will search recursively. To list only files in the current directory:

```
find . ! -name . -prune  -type f -name '*c*' -name '??'
```

Comment: with the caveat about discovering subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1` would help for GNU find)

Comment: @ Jeff Schaller here too We'll need clarification on whether we search the file in the courrant directory or anywhere :)

Comment: gnu ls have a option  --hide=PATTERN so I try ls \*c\* --hide='?' --hide='???*' but it's buggy or I don't know how to use it

Comment: It works just like `-I`  ... it's not buggy, it only works if you don't specify a pattern for `ls` (that's what they mean by `implied entries` - whatever `ls` would print by default... if you run `ls *c* ...` that's no longer implicit, it's explicit...)

Comment: With hide, this works: `ls --hide='?' --hide='???*' --hide='[^c][^c]'`.

Answer (score 3):

If the files exist (and have no escaped characters like `\c`), you can use a glob:

```
echo ?c c?
```

that will match files that have one character (`?`) followed by a `c` or that have a `c` followed by one character (`?`).

But will fail with file **names** that start with a dash like `-n` or `-e` or with backslash characters like `\c` or `\n` with `echo` as both `-e` and `-n` are special to (some shells) `echo` and `\c` or `\n` would be interpreted as an escape sequence (`\c` ends output and `\n` prints a new line, not the verbatim characters `\n` in some shell implementation of echo and with bash when the option `shopt -s xpg_echo` is set). Other applications or utilities (like `ls`) will have some other options and may fail with many other dash-started or interpret other escape characters in file names.

Will also list a file named `cc` twice.

- If a file may start with a dash (like -n), use:

  ```
  $ ls -d -- ?n 
  -n
  ```

  Or, better:

  ```
  $ ls -d ./?n
  ./-n
  ```

#### Caveats

- Glob match no file.

  1. If the files do not exist, the glob will not be expanded and the glob will be printed in their original form.

     ```
     $ echo ?m m?
     ?m m?
     ```
  2. Except in zsh.

     ```
     $ zsh -c 'echo ?m m?'
     zsh:1: no matches found: ./m?
     ```

     The shell will exit with an error.
     This behavior is controlled by [Zsh's `nomatch`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Expansion-and-Globbing) option.

     ```
     $ zsh -c 'setopt +o nomatch; echo ?m m?'
     ?m m?
     ```

     Or:

     ```
     $ zsh -c 'echo ?m(N) m?(N)'
     ?m m?
     ```

     But that will print `mm` twice.
  3. In bash you could get a similar result to zsh if the shell option `failglob` is set:

     ```
     $ bash -c 'shopt -s failglob; echo ?m m?'
     bash: no match: ?m
     ```

     But the script will not stop, the shell will not exit. Well, technically, the line where the glob is used is not executed further but execution resumes on next script line.
  4. In bash you could set the option `nullglob` to remove globs that don't match:

     ```
     $ bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; echo ?m m? done'
     done
     ```
- Using ls (similar with other programs)

  1. With matching files there will be no problem, but will also match (and list) directories:

     ```
     $ ls ?c c?
     bc  cz  sc

     ac:
     hjk
     ```

     Beter use `-d` with `ls` (directories will be included but not expanded).

     ```
     $ ls -d ?c c?
     ac bc cz sc
     ```
  2. Globs failing to match a file (or a directory)

     Then `ls` will report a failure

     ```
     $ ls ?m m?
     ls: cannot access '?m': No such file or directory
     ```

     Other programs might (probably) do **not** do similar checks.
  3. Using `nullglob` with bash will give an empty list to ls, so, it will list the contents or the pwd as if only `ls` was executed:

     ```
     $ ls ?m m?
     ac a.out cz 3 b sc ab bc
     ```

     That could be avoided using `./`

     ```
     $ ls -d ./?m ./m?
     ls: cannot access './?m': No such file or directory
     ls: cannot access './m?': No such file or directory
     ```

Or you can use a find regex (but it will traverse subdirectories with `prune` missing) (Note that this will not repeat a file called cc):

```
    $ find . ! -name . -prune -regex '.*/\(.c\|c.\)'
    ./ac
    ./cc
    ./sc
    ./bc
    ./cz
```

Comment: `bash` exits in `bash -c 'shopt -s failglob; echo ?m m?; echo not reached'`. Note that the `nomatch` zsh option name comes from csh/tcsh. The behaviour is slightly different though between csh and tcsh. See the `cshnullglob` option in `zsh` to emulate csh's (or pre-Bourne shells using /etc/glob) behaviour. `fish` now also behaves like `zsh`/`bash -o failglob` except that failing matches don't exit the shell.

Comment: Exit? Only if both commands are in one line, try `bash -c $'shopt -s failglob; echo ?m m?\n echo not reached'`. Or (I don't recomend this) `bash -c eval\ $'shopt -s failglob; echo ?m m?\n echo not reached'`. I tested it inside an script, one command per line. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Hmmm, the rest seems to be too much information for one answer IMhO. As the answer is tagged bash, I believe that I will pass adding that. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Technically, `failglob` in an interactive shell will bring you back to the prompt (unless the failed glob happened in a subshell). And it's the same in scripts, it resumes execution at the next line the shell would read. So for instance, if the failing glob happens in a function and not in a subshell there, that aborts the function and whatever other commands that were _connected_. It's a bit messed up. (bash also doesn't have any exception catching like zsh's `always {...}`).

Comment: Technically, don't you think that it is useful to other users to say that bash will not (in all cases) stop executing an script. zsh stops in all cases. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Isaac, what happens in `echo ?c` if there’s a file named `-c`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No problem.  `echo ?c` will list all files even those with a dash as the `-c` option is not special to echo (in any version of shell AFAAICT). Some detail added.

Comment: @JeffSchaller `echo '\c'` would be a problem though in zsh or if the `xpg_echo` option were enabled in bash

Comment: True, better safe than sorry ... :-) editing.

Answer (score 2):

### In `bash`:

- Either `c` followed by a character (`?c`) or a character (including `.` with `dotglob`) followed by `c` (`?c`).

  ```
  shopt -s extglob failglob dotglob
  printf '%s\n' @(?c|c?)
  ```
- All files but those that either don't contain `c` (`!(*c*)`) or are not two characters (`!(??)`). Here using a double-negation to achieve conjunction.

  ```
  shopt -s extglob failglob dotglob
  printf '%s\n' !(!(*c*)|!(??))
  ```

### In `zsh`:

- `printf '%s\n' (?c|c?)(D)`

  (where `D` enables `dotglob`; `failglob` (called `nomatch` in `zsh`) is on by default there).
- double negation using the `~` *except* operator and `^` negation extended operators:

  ```
  set -o extendedglob
  printf '%s\n' *c*~^??(D)
  ```

### In `ksh93`:

- there's no `nomatch`/`failglob` option in ksh93, but you can do it by hand there:

  ```
  FIGNORE='@(.|..)' # only ignore . and .. and not the other dotfiles
  files=(~(N)@(?c|c?))
  if ((${#files[@]})); then
    printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
  else
    echo >&2 No match
    exit 1
  fi
  ```

  (where `~(N)` enables `nullglob` for that glob).
- `ksh93` does have a conjunction operator. So here, you can also change the `files=(...)` line to:

  ```
  files=(~(N)@(*c*&??))
  ```

Comment: Maybe add a note for Nullglob as this: `zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" ?m(N) m?(N) yes'`

Comment: Nitpicking: What the original poster (OP) posted: `ls *`  prints results in one line. Your `printf %s\n`` (in all your options) prints one line per result.

Comment: @Isaac, ++Nitpicking, `ls *` prints one file per line unless stdout is a tty device in which case the format is "implementation-defined" per POSIX and in practice in most implementations, printed in columns.

Comment: @isaac, `zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" ?m(N) m?(N) yes'` would print `mm`  twice (and may also not give a sorted list). `zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" (?c|c?)(N)'` would print an empty line if there was no matching file. To print no output when there's no matching file: `(){ (($#)) && printf "%s\n" $@; } (m?|?m)(N)` or `() { printf %s $^@$'\n'; } (m?|?m)(N)`. It's actually annoying that there's no simpler command just to print a list of lines given as argument (you'd expect `print -rl` to do that but it doesn't).

Comment: It would be useful both for ls and print (and probably many other utilities) to have an option of `-e` (for **e**mpty) to be used in scripts that will avoid doing anything on an empty list of arguments.

Comment: Note that: Setting options `shopt -s extglob failglob dotglob` (in bash) must be on a separate line to be recognized. setting the options and using a glob on the same line will fail with a syntax error.